# Redux using multiple reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm making a react/redux app that shows recipes. When the app loads I load the first 10 from all users, like a feed. I want to make a page for an individual user that shows all their recipes.

I tried changing the redux store to return all user recipes when I visit their page, but when I go back to the main feed I have to change the store again (first 10 from all users). This changing from 'GET_RECIPES' to 'GET_USER_RECIPES' is causing me problems because since I am loading 10 at a time I need to return ...state + the newly loaded recipes.

Is it bad practice to make a new reducer which just shows user recipes. This seems like my only option. So I would have a reducer for my main feed and then one for when I click on a user page and shows all recipes by user id.

This is my current reducer that isn't working:

```
const recipesReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_RECIPES':
            return [...state, ...action.payload];  //PROBLEMS
        case 'POST_RECIPE':
            return [...state, action.payload];
        case 'GET_USER_RECIPES':
            return [...action.payload]
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default booksReducer;
```

Comment: Where is MongoDB in this logic and how you handle getting first 10 recipes? I mean where and how?

Comment: I added it to the original question. Because every time 10 recipes are loaded, I change the redux to store to append them to the existing recipes. This is conflicting with when I change the state to load all recipes by user. I go back to the feed and it adds to to the state in get all and creates duplicates.

Comment: This is not related to mongodb at all and impossible to answer without knowing the recipe entity's relation. Are recipes shared among users? You probably want to put them in an object where the keys are recipe IDs and then filter them for associated user IDs. When new recipes come in you simply add them to your store. It's unclear what "first 10" means exactly. In what order are they? What's the sorting criteria?

Comment: I mean where you use this? I did not understand how you handle your state but your feed (10 per user), user recipes can be separate. Your post add recipe to a user's recipe state and you can get your feed and dispatch the related action creator. As @timotgl said it is a little bit unclear.

Comment: My redux recipes state is all recipes from all users, 10 at a time. When I click on an individual user page I have to hit the database to get all recipes from that user Id. Having one reducer for this and changing the state is causing me problems, so I am really asking if I can use multiple reducers, one where recipes is from all users, (10 at a time), and another where userRecipes is all recipes from users page we click on.

Comment: I'm not a pro but I think you should have two separate states for that. recipes and user. user state holds user specific things, like their recipes. recipe reducer handles other stuff.

Comment: Thank you. If I loaded all recipes (instead of first 10), then when I clicked on a users page I could just filters the ids of the state and pull out the users ids, never touching the database. But loading 10 at a time makes that impossible.

Comment: So, can't you dispatch an action for user page to get all the recipes instead of getting them through feed state? I think this is related with your db schema but I'm pretty sure you can do what you want.

Comment: Devserkan, I tried dispatching an action to change the feed state to the specific users posts, but then when I go back to the feed and change it again it's causing problems with the way the reducer is set up. So I just want to know if it's bad practice to have a whole new reducer for handling user posts. Is it bad to have two reducers handling similar data?

Answer (score 0):

You could split your reducer state up in an object to be something like:

```
const initialState = {
  recipes: [],
  userRecipes: []
}
```

Then your reducer could work like so:

```
const recipesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_RECIPES':
            return {...state, recipes: action.payload};
        case 'GET_USER_RECIPES':
            return {...state, userRecipes: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

However, lets introduce you to a different approach. It's called normalising your Redux state. The [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) explains this in detail with good examples. Essentially, because the type of data you would typically have in your recipe application is relational/nested you try to organise part of your redux state as if it were a database. Each type of data, i.e. chefs or recipes, would have its own section in your state. This helps to keep your data structure 'flat'.

If you are fairly new to React/Redux and this is just an experimental app or you don't mind perhaps a few more api calls then stick with the first option. State normalisation is very powerful and definitely worth learning about but not always the best option depending on your use case.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me greatly! I am used to loading all data, and anything that needs to be deleted, edited, or read can be pulled out of the main resource by id. But when you are only loading a specific amount of resources (10 recipes at a time this case), everything becomes more complicated.